How to construct a countable series of sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with no rational differences and complete coverage
I had this question in the test and unfortunately I didn't know how to prove it, I would appreciate some help:

Assuming Axiom of Choice, show that there exists a countable series of sets $A_0,A_1,A_2,...\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with the following two properties:
(1) There is no rational difference in any set, that is, there is no $x,y\in A_i$ such that $0<|x-y|\in\mathbb{Q}$
(2) Every real number belongs to at least one of the sets, i.e. $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A_i=\mathbb{R}$.

An observation is that "$x - y$ is rational" is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb R$. In fact this is a type of equivalence relation that you have probably seen before if you've done any abstract algebra...

The relation given by $x\sim y\iff x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a equivalence relation.
Assuming the axiom of choice, we can choose one element of every equivalence class that belongs to the interval $[0,1]$. Denote the set of all those elements with $A$. If $x,y\in A$ and $x\neq y$ then $[x]_\sim\neq [y]_\sim$, which implies that $x-y\notin\mathbb{Q}$.
Now, let $r_1,r_2,\ldots$ be a enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. For every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ consider $$A_k=A+r_k=\{a+r_k:a\in A\}$$ Reasoning as before we get that there are no rational differences on any of the $A_i$.
We then have that $A,A_1,A_2,\ldots$ cover all of $\mathbb{R}$ with no rational differences on any of the sets.

Thank you very much, much clearer! However, I didn't fully understand why there are no rational differences on any of the $A_i$, may you elaborate?
And I'm also not sure that I fully understand why it covers all of $\mathbb{R}$, I would like to make sure that I understand correctly: from the claim that rational difference is an equivalence class, and we defined $A$ to be the set of representatives that cover $[0,1]$, basically the members of $A$ should cover all $[0,1]$, then from the moves we make to each $A_i$ we move $A$ along the entire real line and thus cover the whole thing?

@eitan.sh21 Take $x,y\in A_i$. Then $x=a+r_i$, $y=b+r_i$ for some $a,b\in A$. Thus, $x-y=a-b$. As there are no rational differences on $A$, it follows that there aren't any on the $A_i$ either. For your second question, yes, that is what we are doing. To make it more explicit, taking any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it belongs to some equivalence class. Per construction of $A$, there is some $y\in A$ in the same equivalence class, so $x-y=r_i$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and thus $x\in A_i$.
